# Finding all A1 style references in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not a fan of A1 style references - I strongly prefer to use either a structured references when my data is in a table, or name the range and refer to the named range.

I'm mostly done refactoring a large spreadsheet to use all named ranges and structured references, and I'm trying to hunt down the last few cell references.

Searching for $ found me most of them, but I'm wondering if there's a good way to do one last search to find the remaining A1 style references.

Comment: Use VBA. Search all cells with formulas (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065541) containing a regex (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835) of a cell reference: not letter, 1 or more uppercase letters, one or more digits, (not digit or end of string)